# Describe the relationship between thought and intelligence

Tags: single-word-requests

I suppose this could be interpreted as a philosophical question, but I'm asking it as an English one because I think there's a perfect word for this  that's escaping me.

Some words I think are [*almost* right](http://www.quotespedia.info/images/right/mark_twain_right_69.jpg):

Thought is **the medium of** intelligence.

Thought is **the vehicle of** intelligence.

Thought is **a conduit for** intelligence.

Maybe even: Thought is **the stuff of** intelligence.

I don't feel like any of these nail it though - can someone suggest a word that does? Or is one of the above the best I'm going to do?

Comment: I don't know that there's any correlation between thought and intelligence... people think a lot of really stupid, incorrect things.

Comment: @Catija I see your point, but on a more elemental level, thinking stupid things is still an exercise in intelligence - just not very strenuous exercise :-P In all seriousness, it's that elemental level that I'm thinking about here.

Comment: @drewmore Ah yes thank you for bring that to my attention, (comment deleted)

Comment: @drewmore Ought we delete these?!

Comment: Perhaps "thought is the essence of intelligence"?

Comment: What @Catija said. The dividing line between *[analytical] **thought*** and *[often, quite unthinking] **emotion*** is fuzzy, to say the least. Plus there's not necessarily a high correlation between being ***intelligent*** and being ***sensible***, and we customarily refer to things like "intelligent control systems" which clearly have no capacity for what most of us would call "thought", so I think if there *is* an "answerable" question here, it would require OP to define what exactly *he* means by thought and intelligence.

Comment: Maybe you can give some more context because there is not a single relationship between the two.

Comment: @drewmore: Comments aside, it's not our job as respondents to "philosophise" on this matter. But if you can describe (in as many words as necessary) exactly what your two terms mean [to you, in this context], ***and*** the nature of the relationship you posit / want to reference, it may be possible for someone to find appropriate terminology to describe it even they don't agree that it truly reflects reality. If you can't provide such a description though, it probably is Off Topic.

Comment: '__Thought__ is the language of __intelligence__', '__thought__ is the river through which __intelligence__ flows', '__thought__ is the epiphenomenon of barely coordinated functional modules of neuronal collections expressing itself externally through what other biomasses superficially ascribe to __intelligence__'

Comment: thought is a *process* of intelligence.  (by intelligence I'm assuming any sentient being)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought is the ***manifestation*** of intelligence.

*Manifestation* - the demonstration, revelation, or display of the existence, presence, qualities, or nature of some ... thing (OED)